# How to implement custom JSQMessagesInputToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Is it possible to implement custom [JSQMessagesInputToolbar](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Views/JSQMessagesInputToolbar.h) for [JSQMessagesViewController](http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/)?

I need to set custom `UIToolbar`, but `inputToolbar` [property](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.h#L46) of class `JSQMessagesViewController` is readonly and initialized from `.xib`, so I have no idea how to insert overridden implementation of `JSQMessagesInputToolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Category and replace the implementation of the method
**loadToolbarContentView** method. This basically replaces the implementation of the original function with the function you define.

So Create a Category with the following .h file :

```
#import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController.h>
@interface JSQMessagesInputToolbar (InputCategory)
@end
```

And the following .m file

```
#import "JSQMessagesInputToolbar+InputCategory.h"
@implementation JSQMessagesInputToolbar (InputCategory)

- (JSQMessagesToolbarContentView *)loadToolbarContentView
{
    //this is called once in the loadNib and returns the toolbar

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"updatedXib" owner:self options:nil];
    return topLevelObjects.firstObject;
    //self.preferredDefaultHeight = 84.0f; this could also be useful
}
@end
```

You might also want to extended an implementation of **JSQMessagesViewController** to handle the specific behaviour of the updatedXib UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same question,so I explore the JSQMessagesViewController issues;

The issue 358: said that the author is not going to support this any time soon, because other features have higher priority and no one else has requested this. And the author suggest us to fork and customize it.

[The other issue](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1068) is asking the same question and there is a example using Frame to add a second button.

I don't think it's a good example.

I think my demo below is better.

In the `viewDidLoad` method of `JSQMessagesViewController` or subclass

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
JSQMessagesToolbarContentView *contentView= self.inputToolbar.contentView;
[contentView.leftBarButtonContainerView addSubview:btn];//add the new button

contentView.leftBarButtonItemWidth=66; //make containerView wider to hold more buttons
//remove unused leftBarButtonItem constraint
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in contentView.leftBarButtonItem.superview.constraints) {
    if(constraint.secondItem ==contentView.leftBarButtonItem &&constraint.firstAttribute ==NSLayoutAttributeLeading){
        constraint.active=NO;
    }
}
// update two button constraint
[contentView.leftBarButtonItem mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.width.equalTo(@30);
}];

[btn mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(btn.superview.mas_top);
    make.bottom.equalTo(btn.superview.mas_bottom);
    make.left.equalTo(btn.mas_left);
    make.width.equalTo(@30);
}];
```

Result like this:
[InputToolBarContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9j6w.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 version** of [Shawn Wang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019348/how-to-implement-custom-jsqmessagesinputtoolbar/35874065#35874065)

```
        let button = UIButton(type: .infoDark)
        if let contentView = self.inputToolbar.contentView {

            contentView.leftBarButtonContainerView.addSubview(button)
            contentView.leftBarButtonItemWidth = 66

            for constraint in contentView.leftBarButtonItem.superview!.constraints {

                if (constraint.secondItem  as? UIButton) == contentView.leftBarButtonItem && constraint.firstAttribute == .leading {
                    constraint.isActive = false
                }
            }

            contentView.leftBarButtonItem.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
                make.width.equalTo(30)
            })

            button.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
                make.top.equalTo(button.superview!.snp.top)
                make.bottom.equalTo(button.superview!.snp.bottom);
                make.left.equalTo(3);
                make.width.equalTo(30);
            })
        }
```

I have used [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) for autoLayout